# How to make php script to take information from javascript and the write it in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hello I'm trying to make PHP script that pulls coordinates from this JavaScript (or from here http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.geojsonp) and write them to mysql.
How to do that please make me tutorial?

```
<script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 2,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8,-187.3),
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        // Create a <script> tag and set the USGS URL as the source.
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        // This example uses a local copy of the GeoJSON stored at

        script.src = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/json/earthquake_GeoJSONP.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      }

      // Loop through the results array and place a marker for each
      // set of coordinates.
      window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
          var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1],coords[0]);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```

Comment: "please make me tutorial?". Sure, who can I make the invoice out to? Nobody is going to write the code for you. Try figure it out and post specific questions of what you get stuck on. The first thing you need to do is send the data to the server, read up on ajax, and get started there

Comment: `please make me tutorial` like an instant to-go tutorial!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the tutorial you want : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp